# Swift - using @available attribute to block a throwing function

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, function, attributes

I'm working on an app that uses Obj-C and Swift.  In Swift, I have a throwing function that should only be used with iOS 9.3 or above:

```
@objc class NewClass: NSObject, WCSessionDelegate {
    ...
    @available(iOS 9.3, *)
    func updateContent(username: String, password: String) throws {
        guard let session = session where session.state == .Activated else { // app is crashing on this line
            return
        }
        do {
            ...
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
        ...
    }

    @available(iOS 9.3, *)
    func session(session: WCSession, state: WCSessionActivationState, error: NSError?) {
        do {
            ...
        } catch 
            print(error)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

But, when running the code above on a iOS 9.1 device, the app crashes in function updateContent at:

```
guard let session = session where session.state == .Activated else {
```

If, however, I rewrite function updateContent as follows, the app runs fine:

```
func updateContent(username: String, password: String) throws {
    guard #available(iOS 9.3, *) else {
        return
    }
    guard let session = session where session.state == .Activated else {
        return
    }
    do {
        ...
    } catch {
        throw error
    }
    ...
}
```

function updateContent is called by AppDelegate.m as follows:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    ...
        [[NewClass sharedManager] updateContent:username password:password error:nil];
    ...
}
```

Can somebody tell me why function updateContent is being run in iOS 9.1 even when preceded by the @available attribute specified for iOS 9.3?

Comment: `@available` is a compile-time construct related to the SDK you use to build the app, not to which OS version the app runs onto. See more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html).

Comment: Thanks, @Cristik!